# MySQL REGEXP doesn't return expected result for Arabic-based regex

Tags: mysql, regex, select

I am having a strange behavior when trying to search MySQL DB v5.6 with an arabic regex.

I tried my regex more than once at online regex testers and they found a match, however, it doesn't return result in a query.

My regex:

```
    [ا|أ|إ|آ]س[ا|أ|إ|آ]م[ه|ة]
```

The statement to find the match, which exists in the DB table I an querying:

```
    أساسيات ريادة الأعمال أسامة
```

the SQL Query I used:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE text REGEXP "[ا|أ|إ|آ]س[ا|أ|إ|آ]م[ه|ة]" ;
```

However, the same statement is found when I changed the regex to:

```
    [ا|أ|إ|آ]سام[ه|ة]
```

the query that worked is:

```
    SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE text REGEXP "[ا|أ|إ|آ]سام[ه|ة]";
```

both regex-es generate match on any regex testing website:
https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html , https://regex101.com/ ..etc

but I don't know why the same thing doesn't happen on MySQL!

Any Help?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Worked when I replaced "[", "]" with "(", and ")"

the following regex returned current result set:

```
"(ا|أ|إ|آ)س(ا|أ|إ|آ)م(ه|ة)"
```

thanks alot mr. Rick

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's 5.6 REGEXP does not understand multi-byte characters (such as UTF-8).  Instead, it looks only at bytes.  Furthermore, it does not understand right-to-left ordering of text.

Workarounds:

- Use MySQL 8.0
- Use MariaDB 10.0
- Search via the hex...

Hex of `أساسيات ريادة الأعمال أسامة` is `D8A3D8B3D8A7D8B3D98AD8A7D8AA20D8B1D98AD8A7D8AFD8A920D8A7D984D8A3D8B9D985D8A7D98420D8A3D8B3D8A7D985D8A9`

Hex of `[ا|أ|إ|آ]س[ا|أ|إ|آ]م[ه|ة]` is `5BD8A77CD8A37CD8A57CD8A25DD8B35BD8A77CD8A37CD8A57CD8A25DD9855BD9877CD8A95D`

So...

```
mysql> SELECT HEX('أساسيات ريادة الأعمال أسامة')
    -> REGEXP '^(..)*(D8A7|D8A3|D8A5|D8A2)D8B3(D8A7|D8A3|D8A5|D8A2)D985(D987|D8A9)' as bool;
+------+
| bool |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
```

Shows a REGEXP that does work.

There was a problem in your original attempt -- [] vs ().  `[]` is used for "character classes", as in `[0123456789]`, which matches any one digit.  You were using `|` in it:  `[0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9]`, which matches a digit *or* a `|`.  Alternatively, `(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)` matches any digit, but it means test for `0` *or* `1` *or* ....  Notice how I had to use `(|)` when I moved from characters to hex strings.

The leading `^(..)*` is to skip over an even number of hex digits, so that it can stay in synch with the bytes.

Comment: @ibrahimali - Your welcome; it was a fun challenge.  Alternatively, you could update your MySQL 8.0 / MariaDB 10.0 to get a REGEXP that works directly with utf8 characters.